# QuarkusBindException when running multiple test classes annotated with @QuarkusIntegrationTest

Tags: quarkus

I am building a maven project with Kotlin and Quarkus. I splitted unit and integration tests so I have a structure like :

- `src/`

  - `integration-test/` -> where I annotate classes with `@QuarkusIntegrationTest`
  - `main/`
  - `test/` -> where I annotate classes with `@QuarkusTest`

I have an issue when trying to run all tests in `integration-test` (with mvn failsafe command, or with intelliJ). All the tests inside the first test class pass, but then the application fails to start before running tests of the second test class, stating that application port is already in use:

```
io.quarkus.runtime.QuarkusBindException: Port(s) already bound: 8081: Address already in use
```

When running each test class separately, all tests pass.

I have tried setting `test-port: 0` in my application.yml, but I get the same error with the random port. Is there a way to tell quarkus to keep the same app instance for all integration test class ? Or to check that the first one has teminated completely before running the next class ? I don't know what I am doing wrong with this `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` annotation.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a project to share?

Comment: Sadly not here as this is enterprise code

Comment: Any chance you can create a sample that replicates the behavior you describe?

Comment: This is weird; I can't reproduce my issue with a fresh quarkus project. I will try to discriminate what is causing this behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this was a dumb issue; One of my test was annotated @QuarkusTest instead of @QuarkusIntegrationTest.